# Accessing jQuery script outside function

Tags: jquery

I activate a jQuery script like this:

```
$('#an-id').drawbox();
```

This is the jQuery script (the important part):

```
(function($)
{
$.fn.extend(
{
    drawbox: function()
    {

        // Default options
        var defaults = {
            caption:       'Caption',
            // Canvas properties
            lineWidth:     3,
            lineCap:       'round',
            lineJoin:      'round',
            miterLimit:    10,
            strokeStyle:   'green',
            fillStyle:     'none',
            shadowOffsetX: 0.0,
            shadowOffsetY: 0.0,
            shadowBlur:    0.0,
            shadowColor:   'none',
        }

        options = $.extend(defaults);

        return this.each(function()
        {

            //etc
```

The script runs fine, but I want to later get the 'options' value in a separate script. I'm guessing the options setting is set and stored in the function and can be retrieved later.

I've tried things like:

```
$('#an-id').drawbox.options
```

...but can't seem to get it.

Comment: This: `options = $.extend(defaults);` looks very wrong to me. I think you need "options" to be a parameter to the function, and then that line should look like `options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);`  As you've got it now, "options" is an implicit global (bad) and it'll be set to be a reference to the global jQuery object.

Comment: You need to get the options by parameter, and merge the param options with the property defaults, overwriting the defaults properties with options properties, or lefting default if options are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `drawbox()` method, but it seems you currently have it setup to only execute one internal function. To do what you want, you must setup your plugin to allow multiple methods...

The general `jquery approved` method of doing this is to include all of your methods into a `methods object`, inside your plugin code, where the function `init` is your default function, like so...

```
var methods = {
  "getOptions" : function(){ return options; },

  "init" : function(){
    return this.each(function(){
      //your current code goes here (what happens when you call $().drawbox)
    });
  }
}
```

Now, you must include the following code, or something similar, to get your plugin to call the methods you want...

```
  $.fn.drawbox = function(method){
    if(methods[method]){
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }else if(!methods[method]){
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }else{
      $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.drawbox');
    }      
  };
```

Notice what this does. When `.drawbox()` is called, the above executes, if no parameter is passed, your `init` function is called. If a parameter is passed, such as `drawbox('getOptions')`, the `getOptions` method (in the methods object) is executed.

This way you can return any variables that are inside the scope of your plugin, similar in concept to normal getter/setters. You also need to remove the line `drawbox : function(){...` in your current code, as the above replaces this.

Answer (score 1):

Look:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.yourPlugin = function(options) {
         options= jQuery.extend({ opt: 1, opt2: 2 }, options);
         // the escope of your plugin....
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You need to get the options by parameter, and merge the param options with the property defaults, overwriting the defaults properties with options properties, or lefting default if options are empty

Answer (score 1):

drawbox is a function, so this line is invalid:

```
$('#an-id').drawbox.options
```

and calling `$('#an-id').drawbox()` will execute the code each time which is incorrect.

You have to use parameters in the constructor method so that you can return the options like this

```
$('#an-id').drawbox('options')
```

look at the accordion implementation, i think it does something like what you need:

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-option